# How to change the colour of multiple selected item of listview in android

Tags: android

How to change the color of multiple selected item of list view in android.
While on item click of list view, it should color all the multiple click item.

Comment: Use a custom adapter for your listview.

Answer (score 0):

Create a state_style.xml in your drawable directory and use the Selector element to define your list item's stateDrawables.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@color/myColor1"
    />

<item android:state_selected="true"
    android:drawable="@color/myColor2"/>


//default state
<item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>

</selector>
```

Then set your list item's background to the state_style.xml